# Sending file via CURL

Tags: image, file, curl, post, base64

I have a script that doesn't work correctly. I'm new to CURL.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpfile=$(mktemp)

base64 -w 0 0.jpeg > "$tmpfile"

curl -X POST "https://image.octoai.run/upscaling" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $OCTOAI_TOKEN" \
     -d "{
         \"model\": \"real-esrgan-x4-plus\",
         \"scale\": 2,
         \"init_image\": \"@$tmpfile\",
         \"output_image_encoding\": \"jpeg\"
     }"

rm "$tmpfile"
```

Error:
`{"message":"Error decoding provided base64 image in 'init_image' field. Base64 string is not a valid image."}`

I tried sending the base64 code directly as string, but when I use large images I get the "Argument list too large" error. Only works with small images.

```
#!/bin/bash
export BASE64_IMAGE=$(base64 -w 0 large_image.jpeg)

curl -X POST "https://image.octoai.run/upscaling" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $OCTOAI_TOKEN" \
     -d "{
         \"model\": \"real-esrgan-x4-plus\",
         \"scale\": 2,
         \"init_image\": \"$BASE64_IMAGE\",
         \"output_image_encoding\": \"jpeg\"
     }"
```

Comment: Well first guess is that JSON does not allow literal newlines.

Comment: Where is the new line? Inside the tmpfile?

Comment: Well, did you take a look?